# Cut duplicate words from text

Tags: string, duplicates

I have text with following strings:

```
{whatever}:::duplicateString:::{whatever}
{whatever}:::duplicateString:::{whatever}
....
{whatever}:::duplicateString:::{whatever}
{whatever}:::duplicateString:::{whatever}
```

How to remove **duplicateString** from text: the main idea is remove second word from line if it occurs more then one times.

First idea was to read them line-by-line and split by "**:::**" in order to create arrays and iterate over arrays with adding entries to TreeSet. Good. But how then to glue up lines again?

I can't to remember any mechanism to figure out such task.. Language doesn't matter, just approx solution?

Example text:

```
Appliances:::Main
Appliances:::Main:::Appliance Warranties
Appliances:::Main:::Beer Keg Refrigerators
Appliances:::Main:::Beverage Refrigerators
Appliances:::Main:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories
Appliances:::Main:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories
Appliances:::Main:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories:::Downrod Couplers
Appliances:::Main:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories:::Downrods
Appliances:::Main:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories:::Fan Replacement Blades
```

ideally it must be like:

```
Appliances:::Main
Appliances:::Appliance Warranties
Appliances:::Beer Keg Refrigerators
Appliances:::Beverage Refrigerators
Appliances:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories
Appliances:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories
Appliances:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories:::Downrod Couplers
Appliances:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories:::Downrods
Appliances:::Ceiling Fans & Accessories:::Accessories:::Fan Replacement Blades
```

Comment: It is hard to determine exactly what you are looking for here.  Could you show your strings *before **and** after* so that it is more clear?

Comment: So in the first line you don't want to remove the word.

Comment: yes. just duplicated second word, saving remain line. if word will be only in first line - there are no duplicates =)

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect that you want to delete the word if it was the same as in the previous line. I think you need some variation of this.

Comment: the main idea is remove second word from line if it occurs more then one times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  duplicateString possibly only occurs as the 2nd word, you could do (in Python):

```
lastWord = None
for line in open('file.txt'):
  w = line.split(':::')
  thisWord = w[1]
  if lastWord==w[1]:
    del w[1]
  lastWord = thisWord
  print ':::'.join(w)
```

Comment: before duplicateString just one word, but after can occurs any amount of words separated by ":::"